# Object type "Places" cannot be attached to custom actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to attach the object type "places" to "share" I get the error:

"Sorry, place is reserved and can't be used. Try something more descriptive."

Unlike "image" which can't be added at all as an object id, place seems like a default item.

Is this a bug?